# Why does this loop yield $\pi/8$?

Tags: algorithms, pi

Was doing some benchmarks for the mpmath python library on my pc with randomly generated tests.

I found that one of those tests was returning a multiple of $\pi$ consistently. I report it here:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps=50

print "correct pi: ", pi

den=mpf("3")
a=0
res=0

for n in xrange(0,1000):
    res=res+1/den
    a=a+32
    den=den+a

print "result:     ", res*8
```

Result:

```
correct pi:  3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
result:      3.1410926536210432286970258295579986968615976706527
```

The convergence rate is very low. 10000 terms only give accuracy to the 5th-4th decimal digit. Is it there somewhere a formula for pi that involves the number 32?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per String's answer, continuing from his result we have
\begin{align*}
  res &= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16i(i+1)+3}\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4i+1)(4i+3)} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4i+1}-\frac{1}{4i+3}\right) \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \cdots\right) \\
    &= \frac{\pi}{8}.
\end{align*}
This derivation also explains why the series converges so slowly....this particular approximation converges as the alternating harmonic series converges to zero, which is very slow.

Comment: That is a great way to put it, I think!

Comment: Nicely done - note that you can use "\infty" to get the infinity symbol.

Comment: @nbubis Right. No morning coffee. Thanks. Getting confused between MMA's inf and Latex's.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is equivalent to the the sum:
$$\pi'=8\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3+32}+\frac{1}{3+32+64}+\frac{1}{3+32+64+96}+\ldots\right)$$
Or:
$$\pi'=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{8}{3+16k(1+k)}=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(1/4+k)(3/4+k)}$$
These sums can be expressed as digamma functions, since:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(a+k)(b+k)}=\frac{1}{b-a}\left(\psi(b)-\psi(a)\right)$$
Finally, we are left with:
$$\psi(3/4)-\psi(1/4)$$
Which by the identity:
$$\psi(1 - x) - \psi(x) = \pi\,\!\cot{ \left ( \pi x \right ) }$$
Is indeed equal to $\pi$.

Comment: While I realize that your answer provides more advanced concepts, I prefer Rogerl's answer as it shows how, after all, my algorithm turns out to be just an obscure way to rewrite the Gregory–Leibniz series. Nice work tho, you got my +1.

Comment: @user2464424 - I think Rogel's answer is better as well :)

Answer (score 2):

From your program one can infer that we must have
$$
den_n=f(n)=32 T(n)+3
$$
Where $T(n)=1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is a so-called [Triangular Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Then you form the sum
$$
\begin{align}
res_n&=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{f(i)}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{32 T(i)+3}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{16i(i+1)+3}\\
\end{align}
$$
So the question remains: is this series approximating $\pi/8$ and why ... Others have elaborated on that :)

Comment: See my answer as to why $\pi/8$...

Comment: @nbubis: Impressive! So many things one does not know ...